# Slow down Jquery image slider after one cycle

Tags: jquery, slider

i want to slow down my image slider on www.debruiloft-dj.nl after 1 cycle of the three images.

So after one cycle it slows down for example with 50% compared the previous cycle.

Is there a solution for this problem, thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the relevant code and if possible, in addition, a fiddel on jsFiddle.net would help too. Simply posting link to a site is not usefull to anyone possibly needing a similar solution to a similar issue in the future when link-rot sets in.

Answer (score 0):

use the  delay: -1000(any time u wish in milliseconds) after ur code for cycle of images